# Joining on multiple tables in teradata

Tags: sql, database, inner-join, teradata

Please help me through this

```
sel a.col1,a.co2,a.col3,.........b.col1,b.col2..,c.col1,c.col2
from table1 as a inner join table2 as b on a.col1 =b.col1
inner join table3 as c on a.col1 = b.col1
where col1 = xxxxx;
```

Now i need join one more table table4. As table4 dont have col1 as primary index in it I need to join this to another table which has Primary key.

The below is the different query which i need inculde this in to the above sel statement.

```
Sel xx.col1,yy.aaa,yy.bbb,zz.ccc,zz.ddd,zz.eee
from tablea as xx, tableb as yy, table4 as zz
where xx.col1 = yy.bbb and yy.aaa = zz.ccc
```

Primary indexs :

- col1 for table1,table2,table3,tablexx
- aaa for tableb
- ccc for table4

Thanks in advance

Comment: THIS IS IN TERADATA------------

My trail:

sel

a.col1,

a.co2,

a.col3,.........b.col1,b.col2..,c.col1,c.col2,zz.ccc,z z.ddd,zz.eee

from table4 as zz,table1 as a inner join table2 as b on a.col1 =b.col1

inner join table 3 as c on a.col1 = b.col1

inner join tableb as yy on a.col1= yy.bbb and yy.aaa = zz.ccc

where col1 = xxxxx;

 

Error: 3782 Improper coloumn reference in the search condtion of the joined table

Thanks

Comment: It seems that in the process of making the table names and column names generic you have introduced some mistakes. Because of this it is hard to know whether you are running into problems because your original code had syntax errors or if you introduced them when translating to generic names. Here is an example of something clearly wrong in your code. You wrote in the first code block "table 3 as c". I assume you meant "table3 as c."  Please either post the actual sql with example tables or triple check that your translated SQL is correct

Comment: @snoguy . . . it is possible that I introduced a stray space when I reformated the query.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Select a.leg,c.btn,p.prods,svc.sr,speed.test, a.leg, b.acct_id, e.emp_no, e.emp_name
FROM db1.tb1 as a 
    inner join db1.tb2 as C ON a.leg = C.leg 
    inner join db1.tb3 as p ON a.leg = p.leg 
    inner join db1.tb3 as svc on a.leg = svc.leg 
    inner join db2.tb4 as speed on a.leg = speed.leg
    inner join db4.tb1 as b on a.leg = b.sce_acct_id
    inner join db4.tb5 as e on b.acct_id = e.acct_id
where a.leg ='xxxx'
```

Comment: Select
a.leg,c.btn,p.prods,svc.sr,speed.test FROM  db1.tb1 as a  
INNER JOIN db1.tb2 as C
   ON a.leg=C.leg
INNER JOIN db1.tb3 as p
   ON a.leg=p.leg
inner join db1.tb3 as svc
on a.leg = svc.leg
inner join db2.tb4 as speed
on a.leg = speed.leg where leg ='xxxx' second query
SELECT a.leg,b.acct_id,c.emp_no,c.emp_name
         
   FROM  db1.tb1 a,
                                db4.tb1 b,
                            db4.tb5 c
            
  WHERE  a.leg  = b.sce_acct_id
  AND  b.acct_id = c.acct_id
Now how to join the 2nd query to first query.

Comment: i have provided the answer based on the information you provided in the comment--however please use the site appropriately so that others who find this page can follow. Specifically, that information is necessary to properly answer the question so it should be part of the question--not a comment on my answer.

Comment: @balaji - please stop posting long code in a comment.  Post an answer if it's an answer.  Or edit your question and post it there.

Comment: @snowguy As i am new to this site..I will make sure to follow the terms of the site.